# Why does my site look so terrible in Opera?

Tags: css, opera

http://www.bergstenmusic.com

When I open the site in Opera, the text it huge, and the background of the body only shows up on the homepage (no doubt because of multiple css files-- I'm not sure which properties are correct to display the png background). The navigation also gets pushed to a second line because of the size of the text.

--Fixed: the background caught up to the style sheets after a restart of opera. Navigation still funky--

Any advice for making the site look presentable in Opera? It functions, but man is it ugly!

Thank you!

Comment: Looks pretty much the same to me. Do you have different default settings in Opera?

Comment: looks good here on Opera 11.51

Comment: I'll second @Mr Lister. Looks the same on Opera 11.52 as on Chrome 16 beta.

Comment: Fine on 11.60 - Can you post a image of how it look to you? Maybe try a hard refresh CTRL+F5 encase it cached before any changes you have made.

Comment: This is how the navigation looks: http://i.imgur.com/c7DAb.jpg

Comment: Your Opera for some reason uses **different** font than all other browsers. I expect, it might be Georgia.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on Opera 11.60 on linux.

Isn't it because of zoom? you could reset it back to 100% in Page->Zoom->100% (or Ctrl+0)

or you could check if Opera isn't on User Mode (Page->Style->User Mode)

Comment: I had it zoomed to 100% and when I zoom out, the navigation still pushes itself onto the second line.

Comment: can't you post a screenshot?
you could try enabling Opera Dragonfly to debug it (Ctrl+Shift+I)

Comment: I've done some searching on your issue, looks like the font is kind strange, have found another question that might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909772/why-is-text-rendered-with-a-greater-font-size-in-opera

and please consider using a css reset

Comment: ok. Thank  you! Will do.-- I do have the default font set to Arial, just a note.

Comment: yeah, I checked your css searching for anything else to point as the problem :) ... but your fonts surely looks strange, is TrueType enabled?

Comment: What's true type and how do I enable/disable it?

Comment: http://malektips.com/windows_xp_fonts_0010.html
I think it can help since Opera uses some settings from the OS to render fonts...